# pheatmap scale="row" giving Error in hclust(d, method = method) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: r, heatmap, scaling, na, pheatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap with gene expression values with the package pheatmap in R. I have used the code numerous times and never had a problem untill today. It seems when I do the scale="row" , I end up with this error. I cannot create the z-scores. So probably some rows have no variability for which this is happening. How can I get rid of this. The matrix is having 1100 rows and 9 columns. My code:

```
data  <- read.table("~path/DEGs_DESeq.txt",sep="\t")
data2 <- as.matrix(data[,2:9])
data3 <- data2[-1,]
samples <- data2[1,]
genes <- data[2:length(data2[,1]),1]
vett <- as.numeric(data3)
data4 <- matrix(vett, length(genes), length(samples), dimnames=list(paste(genes),paste(samples))) 
head(data4)

pheatmap(as.matrix(data4), col=bluered(200), scale="row", key=T, keysize=1.5,
    density.info="none", trace="none",cexCol=0.6, fontsize_row=8, fontsize_col=10)
```

**Error in hclust(d, method = method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)**

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I had the same problem and your comment was very helpful in solving the problem. You should list it as an answer. Also this code is what I used: `counts_filtered_df <- counts_df[apply(counts_df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) sd(x) != 0),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I infact worked it out.. i had to remove the rows for which no SD was coming up while performing the z score calculation and it reconstructed the heatmap. Thanks

Comment: Please explain to the rest of us who don't have your dataset (so can't reproduce this) **why `pheatmap(..., scale="row"`) did not compute some SDs**? Was it grouping? Was it groups with a size of one, by any chance? Did your dataset actually have NAs in any rows? Otherwise this question is not a reusable resource.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but was having a similar problem. In my dataset, which I'd checked for non-numeric and NA values, the issue was that there were a few rows with the same value in every column. For these, the SD was 0 and this was screwing up the row scaling. Removing these rows solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the lead Max and addressing the query of the comment. Really appreciate it. I shared the same answer as I solved my own problem. Apologies if it wasn’t clear enough, however Max did clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have all the rows having `0` values in the dataframe